# Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes. how can i solve this error

Tags: image-processing, classification, object-detection-api, data-preprocessing, image-preprocessing

During data augmentation, I define the path of my original dataset, but in the output I recevived this error
"Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes. how can I solve this error"
I want data augmentation in the output directory, I want to save 10 images per images in the output directory, can anyone help me to solve this issue, thanks in adnavece.